# Ruby: Store and update variable inbetween script runs

Tags: ruby

Newbie at ruby here:

I need to create a ruby script that will be executed multiple times as I receive different event data. Each time an event is received, this script will be run.

I'd like the script to access an environment variable and create a new variable based on the environment variable. I'd also like to store that new variable somewhere and access it again when the script is run again (when another event is received).

Is there a way to store a variable and access it between script executions? I thought of storing it in a separate text file then accessing that file, but is there a different way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save it in a file, that's what files are for!

If you only need the variable to be accessed from Ruby (e.g. you don't need to be able to edit the saved file in a text editor), the easy way to do this is with [Marshal](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Marshal.html).

```
data = {a: 1, b: ["two"]}

# save
File.open("savefile", "w") { |f| Marshal.dump data, f }

# load
loaded = File.open("savefile") { |f| Marshal.load f }

loaded == data # true
```

A more robust and stable solution would be to save it as [JSON](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) instead, but that can be tricky if your data don't naturally map to JSON's types.

Comment: But be careful with Marshal as there can be Ruby version issues: "Marshaled data has major and minor version numbers stored along with the object information. In normal use, marshaling can only load data written with the same major version number and an equal or lower minor version number." Should be fine for temporary use though.